# Mean Absolute Error - Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to Python

I have to implement a function that can calculate MAE between 2 images

Here is the MAE formula i have learnt:[image]

Here is my code:

```
def calculateMAE(imageA, imageB):
    """
    Calculate MAE between 2 images
    np: numpy

    """
    mae = np.sum(imageB.astype("float") - imageA.astype("float"))
    mae /= float(imageA.shape[0] * imageA.shape[1] * 255) 

    if (mae < 0):
        return mae * -1
    else:
        return mae
```

Can anyone tell me if my function is right?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `mae = np.absolute(np.subtract(x_true, x_pred)).mean()`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The absolute sign in the mean absolute error is in each entry in the sum, so you can't check whether `mae < 0` after you summed it up - you need to put it inside the sum!

Hence you should have something like

```
mae = np.sum(np.absolute((imageB.astype("float") - imageA.astype("float")))
```

Where `np.absolute(matrix)` calculates the absolute value element-wise.

Comment: I gave an example. You can check it out from numpy [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html).

Comment: mae = np.sum(np.absolute(imageB.astype("float") - imageA.astype("float")))
mae /= float(imageA.shape[0] * imageA.shape[1] * 255) 

return mae

Is it right bro?

Comment: They probably meant for it to be np.mean() instead of np.sum() to represent the "mean" absolute error